# Get elements by class with javascript in Objective-C return empty string

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, objective-c, string

I'm trying to get elements by class using Javascript, but I get always a empty string. This is the code:

```
 NSString * mystring = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                       @"function parse(el) { 
                                      var _parsed = el[0]; 
                                     return {parsed: _parsed } ; 
                        } 
                        parse(document.getElementsByClassName('out3')).parsed;"];
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<p class="out3">Date:<span class="out4">16/01/1998</span></p>
```

I want to get "16/01/1998".
Thank you in advance.

Comment: please, edit your code. I know Perl too, as i know Objective-C, but i don't want to read Objective-C code with Perl style!

Comment: I don't understand you. I don't know Perl...

Comment: but you write your code like many Perl-coders do, hah, please, make it more readable

Comment: If you say me how can I make it more readable...

Comment: just pust `\n` symbols: \n is a special symbol, which means a newline. 
where you put `\n`, you must click `Return` (or Enter) button :)

Comment: also, please, check your javascript somewhere in browser, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in the browser...